# Перенос строки внутри пункта меню под вопросом

Tags: дефект, дизайн

Видно, что перенос строки находится внутри надписи `закрыть (4)`:

> [image: скриншот]

надо либо использовать неразрывный пробел, либо дополнить стили:

```
.post-menu-container > a { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Что будет, если нажать "мод"?

Comment: @edem, [модераторское меню](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9532/178988) - я его уже четвёртый раз за 2 недели [перетаскиваю в конец](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6238/178988).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, зато у меня фикс есть)

Comment: @Qwertiy обычно на публикуемые фиксы багов разрабам глубоко плевать

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, зато у пользователей могут быть user-стили ;)